# Tool for rna/lna melting temperature prediction

Tags: rna

Is there any tool available to predict the melting temperature for rna/lna oligos with its perfect complement ?

I know this amazing website from qiagen/geneglobe that estimates the tm value.

But is there any command line tool that does this?

I can estimate the normal tm value with RNAcofold and the -T option but there is no lna option.

I searched for a while but i can only find online services.

Answer (score 1):

There are several programs for simulating/predicting DNA melting but you could try them for RNA.
You can look here http://bioinformatics.org/meltsim/wiki/Main/HomePage.

Answer (score 1):

Both [Bio.SeqUtils.MeltingTemp](https://biopython.org/docs/1.75/api/Bio.SeqUtils.MeltingTemp.html) of Biopython and [Primer3](https://primer3.org/) offers different methods/algorithms to calculate the Tm value.